# Validation within nested Blazor components

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, fluentvalidation

I am designing a component in Blazor (.net 8) which contains a number of child components. See the image below:

[image: The CreateBill component, with child Contact and ChargeTerms components]

- The *CreateBill* component is the main container
- There are 3 instances of the *Contact* component
- There is a singular instance of the *ChargeTerms* component

Currently, my application has a submit button (off screen) that executes validation against the whole Model at once:

```
<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="CreateBillOnSubmit">
```

The downside of this is that any validation failures on the model return as just a big list and without any context for the specific component that they came from. For example, if all the contact forms are empty, none of them have any highlighting and all the validation errors are repeated 3 times (see below)

[image: Duplicate error messages]

I'm unsure what the pattern should be for nesting validation, as there's only a single `<Form>` at the root object and the child components (Contact, Charge Terms) do not contain forms, only things like `<InputText>` and so on.

Is there a suggested pattern for having per-field validation errors appear?

Comment: I have a sample project that's attempting to do something similar here: https://github.com/killnine/ValidationPrototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Blazor nested components, you can try and use [`CascadingParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cascadingparameter-attribute) and [`CascadingValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cascadingvalue-component) to provide a validation context to child components. That allows each component to participate in form validation and display errors contextually.

Define a `CascadingParameter` of type `EditContext` in each child component. And register each input's validation within the `OnInitialized` method of the child components by calling `editContext.AddValidationMessageStore`.
Use `DataAnnotationsValidator` or a custom validator to validate the child model. Bind each input to a property of the child component's model.
On the parent component, handle the `OnValidSubmit` event to validate all child components.

In the `Contact` component:

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private EditContext ParentEditContext { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        if (ParentEditContext != null) {
            // Logic to tie this component's validation to the parent EditContext.
        }
    }
}
```

In the `CreateBill` component:

```
<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="CreateBillOnSubmit">
    <CascadingValue Value="_editContext">
        <Contact />
        <Contact />
        <Contact />
        <ChargeTerms />
    </CascadingValue>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private EditContext _editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        _editContext = new EditContext(new CreateBillModel());
    }
    
    private void CreateBillOnSubmit() {
        // Perform the submission logic here
    }
}
```

Do call `Validate` on the `EditContext` to trigger validation for all child components when submitting.

That would  provide a separate validation context for each child component while still being part of the overall form validation. That should eliminate the issue of duplicate error messages and provide contextual feedback to the user.
See also "[ASP.NET Core Blazor forms overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/?view=aspnetcore-8.0)".

Comment: I am marking this is an answer, as I think it contains the root details of what I was looking for (Cascading the EditContext to children). However, I am also posting a link to Steve Sanderson's excellent solution for nested validation using FluentValidation since it is a logical extension of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I greatly appreciate @VonC's solution.

I also wanted to provide the solution Steve Sanderson (@MS) links [here](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/090145d7511c5190f62a409752c60d00) as it worked as a more fully fleshed-out solution.

The key parts are the validation class:

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using System;

namespace CustomValidationSample
{
    public class FluentValidator<TValidator> : ComponentBase where TValidator: IValidator, new()
    {
        private readonly static char[] separators = new[] { '.', '[' };
        private TValidator validator;

        [CascadingParameter] private EditContext EditContext { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            validator = new TValidator();
            var messages = new ValidationMessageStore(EditContext);

            // Revalidate when any field changes, or if the entire form requests validation
            // (e.g., on submit)

            EditContext.OnFieldChanged += (sender, eventArgs)
                => ValidateModel((EditContext)sender, messages);

            EditContext.OnValidationRequested += (sender, eventArgs)
                => ValidateModel((EditContext)sender, messages);
        }

        private void ValidateModel(EditContext editContext, ValidationMessageStore messages)
        {
            var context = new ValidationContext<object>(editContext.Model);
            var validationResult = _validator.Validate(context);
            messages.Clear();
            foreach (var error in validationResult.Errors)
            {
                var fieldIdentifier = ToFieldIdentifier(editContext, error.PropertyName);
                messages.Add(fieldIdentifier, error.ErrorMessage);
            }
            editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
        }

        private static FieldIdentifier ToFieldIdentifier(EditContext editContext, string propertyPath)
        {
            // This method parses property paths like 'SomeProp.MyCollection[123].ChildProp'
            // and returns a FieldIdentifier which is an (instance, propName) pair. For example,
            // it would return the pair (SomeProp.MyCollection[123], "ChildProp"). It traverses
            // as far into the propertyPath as it can go until it finds any null instance.

            var obj = editContext.Model;

            while (true)
            {
                var nextTokenEnd = propertyPath.IndexOfAny(separators);
                if (nextTokenEnd < 0)
                {
                    return new FieldIdentifier(obj, propertyPath);
                }

                var nextToken = propertyPath.Substring(0, nextTokenEnd);
                propertyPath = propertyPath.Substring(nextTokenEnd + 1);

                object newObj;
                if (nextToken.EndsWith("]"))
                {
                    // It's an indexer
                    // This code assumes C# conventions (one indexer named Item with one param)
                    nextToken = nextToken.Substring(0, nextToken.Length - 1);
                    var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Item");
                    var indexerType = prop.GetIndexParameters()[0].ParameterType;
                    var indexerValue = Convert.ChangeType(nextToken, indexerType);
                    newObj = prop.GetValue(obj, new object[] { indexerValue });
                }
                else
                {
                    // It's a regular property
                    var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(nextToken);
                    if (prop == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not find property named {nextToken} on object of type {obj.GetType().FullName}.");
                    }
                    newObj = prop.GetValue(obj);
                }

                if (newObj == null)
                {
                    // This is as far as we can go
                    return new FieldIdentifier(obj, nextToken);
                }

                obj = newObj;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then its addition to the Razor Component:

```
<EditForm Model="customer" OnValidSubmit="SaveCustomer">
    <FluentValidator TValidator="CustomerValidator" />

    <h3>Your name</h3>
    <InputText placeholder="First name" @bind-Value="customer.FirstName" />
    <InputText placeholder="Last name" @bind-Value="customer.LastName" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => customer.FirstName)" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => customer.LastName)" />

    <h3>Your address</h3>
    <div>
        <InputText placeholder="Line 1" @bind-Value="customer.Address.Line1" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => customer.Address.Line1)" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <InputText placeholder="City" @bind-Value="customer.Address.City" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => customer.Address.City)" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <InputText placeholder="Postcode" @bind-Value="customer.Address.Postcode" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => customer.Address.Postcode)" />
    </div>

    <h3>
        Payment methods
        [<a href @onclick="AddPaymentMethod">Add new</a>]
    </h3>
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => customer.PaymentMethods)" />

    @foreach (var paymentMethod in customer.PaymentMethods)
    {
        <p>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="paymentMethod.MethodType">
                <option value="@PaymentMethod.Type.CreditCard">Credit card</option>
                <option value="@PaymentMethod.Type.HonourSystem">Honour system</option>
            </InputSelect>

            @if (paymentMethod.MethodType == PaymentMethod.Type.CreditCard)
            {
                <InputText placeholder="Card number" @bind-Value="paymentMethod.CardNumber" />
            }
            else if (paymentMethod.MethodType == PaymentMethod.Type.HonourSystem)
            {
                <span>Sure, we trust you to pay us somehow eventually</span>
            }

            <button type="button" @onclick="@(() => customer.PaymentMethods.Remove(paymentMethod))">Remove</button>

            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => paymentMethod.CardNumber)" />
        </p>
    }

    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Customer customer = new Customer();

    void AddPaymentMethod()
    {
        customer.PaymentMethods.Add(new PaymentMethod());
    }

    void SaveCustomer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TODO: Actually do something with the valid data");
    }
}
```

The only drawbacks (which were not issues for me) was that it triggers on the submit, while Von's solution could potentially provide more flexibility if you wanted to trigger validation some other point. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Good feedback. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which worked for me. This inherits InputBase and thus there is no additional logic for validation necessary as it seems.

The child component (with Bootstrap CSS classes):

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@inherits InputBase<string>

<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
           class="form-control @CssClass"
           placeholder=""
           autocomplete="on"
           id="@UniqueElementId"
           value="@CurrentValueAsString"
           @oninput="EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString)" />
    <label class="text-secondary" for="@UniqueElementId">@Label</label>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; } = "Name";
    [Parameter] public string UniqueElementId { get; set; } = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// Necessary function to implement InputBase
    /// </summary>
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out string result, out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value ?? string.Empty;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

The component is used in its parent like that:

```
<GenericStringInput Label="Test123" @bind-Value="Testobject.Name" UniqueElementId="Test123"></GenericStringInput>
```

Further [information](https://blazor-university.com/forms/descending-from-inputbase/) regarding inheriting InputBase